# How do I repair a chipped bathtub?

Tags: bathtub

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I patch rusty spots in bathtub?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7947/how-do-i-patch-rusty-spots-in-bathtub)

I have a tub upstairs with a chip in it. Is there an easy way to sand the porcelain down and redo the tub? What would be the most professional way to fix the tub?

Comment: Possibly related to  http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7947/how-do-i-patch-rusty-spots-in-bathtub/7951#7951 - the answer is an enamel repair kit, which is as @mikes says a touch-up kit for tubs.

Answer (score 1):

If the chip is small home centers sell a product similar to touchup paint.I have only seen it in white though and it is for steel or cast iron tubs.

Comment: I've used this stuff on a bathtub and a toilet. Works pretty well. The repair won't be completely invisible, but it makes it far less obvious.